# How to manage a Linux Yocto distribution image between two different memories for its boot and root partitions?

Tags: memory-management, embedded-linux, root, yocto, boot

I am using sama5d27-som1-ek1 board. I built for it Linux distribution using Yocto project. This linux distribution is for SD card. It has two partition : Boot and Root.
I followed the steps described here :

[Yocto_Linux_OS](https://www.linux4sam.org/bin/view/Linu%20...%20EKMainPage)

In the boot partition there are at91bootstrap, u-boot and other files necessary to boot the board.

**Now I want that my board boot from QSPI memory that exists in the SOM of the board. Besides, I want to let the root partion in the SD card**.

What I see in link above, building a linux os image for QSPI memory is not the same as building it for SD memory and when I build another linux distribution for QSPI I think that root and boot are made only to be stored in that QSPI memory.

Is it possible to make the card boots from QSPI while the root is stored in SD memory ? If yes, please tell me how ? Thank you!

Comment: you can probably load the kernel from QSPI and pass root=/dev/mmcblk0pX to the cmd line.

Comment: @Ninic0c0 I build all my Linux image for QSPI memory and after my board boots and work I pass `root=/dev/mmcblk0pX` ?

Comment: @gaston note that `X` needs to be replaced by the correct ID